# Customer Segments in WCMS - Hybris 6.2

Tags: java, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I am using Hybris 6.2.0.10 and not able to see Customer Segments option besides Navigations in WCMS page of Hybris. Do i need to add some extention to bring it? Can anybody please help!

Answer (score 1):

No expert here. You have the btg extensions in your localextensions.xml?

btg
btgcockpit
btghmc

Comment: i checked my localextention file and i've not added this extention. Wil change and see what happens. Thanks for answering my query!